# chaining method of same object

Tags: c++, chaining

I am working on the class right now

But there is a problem of chain of calling method(here is the code

```
class Point{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int i , int j);
    Point incrementX();
    Point incrementY();
    void print();
};
Point::Point(int i, int j){
    x = i;
    y = j;
}
Point Point::incrementX(){
    x++;
    return(*this);
}
Point Point::incrementY(){
    y++;
    return(*this);
}
void Point::print(){
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
}

void Q11(){
    Point a(2,3);
    //(3,4)
    a.incrementX().incrementY().print();
    //(3,3)why 33 here ??
    a.print();
}
```

I am confused why the last code `a.print()` gives the `(3,3)`

and I try to print out the address of `this` inside the method

I found the two address when calling `incrementX()` and `incrementY()` is different

My guessing is that `incrementX()` access to the class, but when calling `incrementY()` the class is occupied. So it make a copy of the class in the heap and then `incrementY()` change the y in the copy...

so the `(3,4)` is printed by copy, and `(3,3)` is printed by actual class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `incrementX` and `incrementY` functions return by value. That is to say that upon return from those functions your object is copied and so subsequent operations occur on a **different instance**.

You could see an error occur in compilation were you to delete the copy constructor. To do that add

```
Point(const Point&) = delete;
```

*(assumes c++11 or greater to use `delete`. If older just make it private)*

So to diagnose your actual error:

1. You construct the `Point` with values *(2, 3)*.
2. The first call to `incrementX` operates on your original instance (which is now value *(3,3)*) and passes out a copy on return.
3. `incrementY` operates on the temporary copy and updates its value to (3, 4). It also returns a copy.
4. You print the second temporary copy with the expected result (3,4).
5. Now `a.print()` displays your original `Point` which has not been touched since the call to `incrementX` and that displays (3,3).

In order to make use of the chaining you wish to use, all of your operations should occur on the **same** object and to achieve that you should return from those functions by non-const **reference**.

The function signature

```
Point Point::incrementX()
```

becomes

```
Point& Point::incrementX()
```

and the complete code looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int i , int j);
    //Point(const Point&) = delete;
    Point& incrementX();
    Point& incrementY();
    void print();
};
Point::Point(int i, int j){
    x = i;
    y = j;
}
Point& Point::incrementX(){
    x++;
    return(*this);
}
Point& Point::incrementY(){
    y++;
    return(*this);
}
void Point::print(){
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
}

int main(){
    Point a(2,3);
    a.incrementX().incrementY().print();
    a.print();
}
```

With the deleted copy constructor this code compiles fine, as no copies are happening.

Answer (score 3):

Only `a.incrementX()` increment the member value. `a.incrementX().incrementY()` increase a temporary instantiation and is discarded.

Replace Point with `Point&` in `Point Point::incrementX()` function, you will get the correct result.